# How to use Azure Docker caching task "Cache@2" to speed up build pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-pipelines-build-task

When I locally build Dockerfile it finishes in few seconds while on the Azure it takes few minutes.
I know that there is new [Cache@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#docker-images) task, but I'm not sure how to implement it into my build.yml file and I didn't found any similar example using it.

Here is my .yml file without caching:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  submodules: false
  
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'MyDockerHub'
    repository: 'myRepo/myservice'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: './MyService/Dockerfile'
    buildContext: './'
    tags: |
      $(Build.BuildId)
      latest
```

Can this be cached in order to improve build speed ?